# Delphi Client-Server Application using Firebird 2.5 error

Tags: delphi

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Delphi Client-Server Application using Firebird 2.5 embedded connection error](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8280184/delphi-client-server-application-using-firebird-2-5-embedded-connection-error)

I have got a lengthy question to ask. First of all Im still very new when it comes to Delphi programming and my experience has beem  mostly developing small single user database applications using ADO and an Access database.

I need to take the transition now to a client server application and this is where the problem starts. I decided to use Firebird 2.5 embeded as my database, as it is open source, and it is can be used with the interbase components in Delphi and that multiple clients can access the database simultanously. So I followed the interbase tutorial in Delphi. I managed to connect the client to the server and see the data in the example (While both are running on my pc), but when i tried to move the client to another pc, keeping the server on mine and running it to see if I can connect to the server it gave me the following error.

Exception EIdSocketError in module clientDemo.exe at 0029DCAC. Socket Error # 10061 Connection refused.

I understand that this might be because the host is defined as localhost in the client. But here is my first question. In the TSQLConncetion you can set die hostname under Driver->Hostname. The thing I want to know is how do you do this at run time, as I cannot get the property when I try and make an edit box to allow the user to enter the value and then set it via code like for example:
    SQLConncetion1.Driver.Hostname := edtHost.text;
The thing is there is not such property to set, so how do you set the hostname at run time?

Im using Delphi XE2

There is still a lot of questions to come especially when it comes to deployment, but I will take this piece by piece and I appreciate the advice.

Answer (score 0):

> That means that the server: port your program is trying to connect to
>   is refusing your connection. Could be a firewall related issue on
>   either your server or your own machine.

Try using telent to connect to the server. If that succeeds you know it a problem with your machine's configuration.

Check these links for more information :
[How TO Fix Socket Error 10061 Connection Refused Easily](http://www.fixerrorcodesnow.com/socket-error-10061-connection-refused)
[Problem Loading (python blocked by firewall)](http://bytes.com/topic/python/answers/556001-problem-loading-python-blocked-firewall-solved)